# Android - wait for runnable to finish

Tags: java, android, runnable, android-handler

I write text to textview letter by letter. Only after the whole text is displayed I want to start running the progress bar. I guess I can achieve it with notify/wait but I don't know how. Any help?

I created `Typewriter` class which extends `Textview`:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

public Runnable characterAdder = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    setText(mText.subSequence(0, mIndex++));
    if (mIndex <= mText.length()) {
      mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);
    }
  }
};

public void animateText(CharSequence text) {
  mText = text;
  mIndex = 0;
  setText("");
  mHandler.removeCallbacks(characterAdder);
  mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);
}
```

and then I use it in Main activity:

```
Typewriter writer = (Typewriter)findViewById(R.id.typewriter);
writer.animateText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
//wait until animation finishes to perform further actions
```

Comment: use a Future object?

Comment: How would I do that? I know nothing about it, I would rather learn how to do this with the basic runnable first.

Comment: @suue do it using join method from Thread class, see this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_join.htm) or [this one](http://www.javatpoint.com/join()-method)

Comment: @rahmatwaisi But I don't explicitely create a new thread; I execute animateText method which uses a runnable. How do I do it in such a scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both my actions run on UI thread I didn't find any synchronization solution. Instead i postponed the second action by the time needed to print all the letters:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    animation.start();
  }
  }, timeNeeded);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like this using Coroutine in Kotlin.

```
val handler = Handler()
var isWaitingHandler = true
GlobalScope.async {
    handler.post {
        // handler does something.
        isWaitingHandler = false    
    }

    while(isWaitingHandler) {
        delay(50)
    }
    Unit
}.await()
```

It is not exactly i wrote, but i think would work.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered some Issues here, where I needed an UI-Update to be performed, while a background-thread is waiting for the ui-part to be done.

So, I wrote a class called UIUtils, which offers an easy access to handler-invocation through two static methods: `invoke()` and `invokeAndAwait()`

`invokeAndAwait()` basically just registers the created `Handler` inside an `awaitingCompletion`-List, and then immediately enters a waiting-loop until the `Handler` is removed from the list again.

If you by accident call `invokeAndAwait()` from the UI-Thread, the passed runnable will be executed as a blocking-call to `run()` instead.

Invoke something in a non-blocking way:

```
//Some code here
UiUtils.invoke(() -> view.setText("abc"));
//More code running right away here.
```

Invoke something in a blocking / awaiting way:

```
//Some code here
UiUtils.invokeAndAwait(() -> view.setText("abc"));
//Code here is running, when invocation is completed.
```

So far, this works pretty flawless for my needs. It is not ideal, because it only checks every 20ms, if the handler is finished, but for the very very very rare usecase, where we need to await the UI-Action to be executed, I can live with that.

```
public class UiUtils {
    private static Object runningBlockingHandlerListLock = new Object();
    private static Collection<Handler> runningBlockingHandlers = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public static boolean isUIThread(){
        return Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread();
    }
    
    public static void invoke(Runnable r){
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(r);
    }
    
    public static void invokeAndAwait(Runnable r){

        if (isUIThread()){
            //On the UI Thread, we cannot juse InvokeAndWait, but we just can run it right away.
            Log.w(UiUtils.class.getSimpleName(), "invokeAndAwait() called on UI-Thread. Using blocking execution of runnable instead.");
            r.run();
            return;
        }

        Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        synchronized (runningBlockingHandlerListLock) {
            runningBlockingHandlers.add(h);
        }

        h.post(() -> {
            try {
                r.run();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(UiUtils.class.getSimpleName(), "Exception during Mainthread invokation", e);
            }finally {
                Log.d(UiUtils.class.getSimpleName(), "Handler completed: " + h.hashCode());
                synchronized (runningBlockingHandlerListLock) {
                    runningBlockingHandlers.remove(h);
                }
            }
        });

        boolean isActive = true;
        while (isActive){
            try {
                Log.v(UiUtils.class.getSimpleName(), "Awaiting completion of Handler: " + h.hashCode());
                Thread.sleep(20);

                synchronized (runningBlockingHandlerListLock) {
                    isActive = runningBlockingHandlers.contains(h);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```